# How to insert data with cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I want insert data with cakephp3 but it dont ok. The insert of data is ok at 50%. I dont have error which is return.

```
        class SeancesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        //$this->hasMany('Exercices');
        $this->hasMany('Series');
        $this->belongsToMany('Exercices');
        $this->addBehavior('TimesTamp');
    }
}

class SeriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('series');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Seances');
        //$this->hasOne('Seances');

    }

    public function add(){

        $requestData = [
            'Seances' =>[
                'commentaire' => 'test cake 33',
                'date_seance' => '2016-02-27',
                'user_id' => 1,
                'Series' => [
                    ['nb_rep' => 17, 'charge' => 520, 'exercice_id'=>1],
                    ['nb_rep' => 27, 'charge' => 600]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $seance = $this->Seances->newEntity($requestData,[
            'associated' => ['Series']
        ]);
       $this->Seances->save($seance);
    }
```

In my database the data Seances are insert but not the series data.
How can i do ?

Thanks and sorry for my english !!

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your code like this**

```
$requestData = [
            'commentaire' => 'test cake 33',
            'date_seance' => '2016-02-27',
            'user_id' => 1,
            'Series' => [
                ['nb_rep' => 17, 'charge' => 520, 'exercice_id'=>1],
                ['nb_rep' => 27, 'charge' => 600]
            ]
    ];

$seance = $this->Seances->newEntity($requestData,[
            'associated' => ['Series']
        ]);

 $this->Seances->save($seance);
```

> When saving hasMany associations, the ORM expects an array of entities
>   at the plural, underscored version of the association name. To Read
>   more.. [Cookbook > Saving Data > Saving hasMay Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations)